# Web API & Entity Framework insert stored procedure ArgumentNullReference exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure to insert a record using Entity Framework. I've gone through multiple tutorials on various related topics and some how managed to get this far. Now getting the error (`ArgumentNullReferenceException`) while consuming the Web API through fiddler.

This is my code:

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsUsers]
    (@user_name nvarchar(50),
     @first_name nvarchar(50),
     @last_name nvarchar(50),
     @mobile_no varchar(10),
     @email nvarchar(50),
     @user_pic varchar(256),
     @strowner int,
     @dbtstamp datetime2)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    INSERT INTO [tbl_users] ([user_name], [first_name], [last_name], [mobile_no], [email], [user_pic], [strowner], [dbtstamp]) 
    VALUES (@user_name, @first_name, @last_name, @mobile_no, @email, @user_pic, @strowner, @dbtstamp);

    SELECT 
        user_id, user_name, first_name, last_name, mobile_no, email, 
        user_pic, strowner, dbtstamp 
    FROM 
        tbl_users 
    WHERE 
        (user_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

Stored procedure mapping:

[image]

Users controller:

```
public class UserDetails
{
            public string user_name { get; set; }
            public string first_name { get; set; }
            public string last_name { get; set; }
            public string mobile_no { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string user_pic { get; set; }
            public int strowner { get; set; }
            public DateTime dbtstamp { get; set; }
}

[Authorize]
[Route("AddUser")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostUsers([FromBody] tbl_users Users)
{
    using(UsersEntities uent = new UsersEntities())
    {
        uent.tbl_users.Add(Users);
        uent.SaveChanges();

        var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Users);
        message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri +
        Users.user_id.ToString());

        return message;
    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Got it. My JSON request was erroneous. Solved.

In earlier solution I was missing the stored procedure itself.

My final working solution looks lie this.

```
[Authorize]
        [Route("Add_User")]

        public HttpResponseMessage PostUsers1([FromBody] tbl_users Users)
        {
            using (var context = new UsersEntities())
            {
                var response = context.spInsUsers(Users.user_name, Users.first_name, Users.last_name, Users.mobile_no,
                    Users.email, Users.user_pic, Users.strowner, DateTime.Now);

                var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Users);
                message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri +
                    response.ToString());

                return message;

            }

        }
```

Thanks.